# Regexes for integer constants and for binary numbers

Tags: regex

I have tried 2 questions, could you tell me whether I am right or not?

1. Regular expression of nonnegative integer constants in C, where numbers beginning with `0` are octal constants and other numbers are decimal constants.

   I tried `0([1-7][0-7]*)?|[1-9][0-9]*`, is it right? And what string could I match? Do you think `034567` will match and `000083` match?
2. What is a regular expression for binary numbers **x** such that **h<sup>x</sup> + i<sup>x</sup> = j<sup>x</sup>**?

I tried `(0|1){32}|1|(10))..` do you think a string like `10` will match and `11` won’t match?

Please tell me whether I am right or not.

Comment: I believe `0000047` is a valid octal literal.

Comment: Also your regex matches `077777777777777777777777777777777777777777777`. This compiles but it gives a warning: 'integer constant is too large for its type'.

Comment: But if an initial 0 means octal, would a value like 07777 be  considered a negative 12-bit number (in a 2's complement sense) ? If 034567 is a 15-bit number and 000083 another, both are positive because the MSB is a zero. I'm not looking at your regexes, here: they're too complicated for me. They don't look right.

Comment: jspcal can u help me with this?

Comment: @unknown: you've asked the same question multiple times.  The last time you asked the h^x + i^x = j^x question, you got some really good answers.  Did you read about Fermat's last theorem on Wikipedia as you were told?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/ for a quick test on whether a particular regex works as you intend it to. This along with google can help you nail the regex you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. `0([1-7][0-7])?|[1-9][0-9]` is wrong because there's no repetition - it will only match 1 or 2-character strings. What you need is something like `0[0-7]*|[1-9][0-9]*`, though that doesn't take hexadecimal into account (as per spec).
2. This one is not clear. Could you rephrase that or give some more examples?

Comment: Hi Max, How did u arrive at this answer, could u throw some light?

Comment: It's pretty simple. There's the basic | branch between the octal on the left and the decimal on the right. The octal starts with a zero and is then followed by any number of digits between 0 and 7. Decimals are the same as your original regex.

Comment: should there be another [1-7] in front of [0-7]*?

Comment: If you want to allow multiple leading zeroes (e.g. 0051) then no.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex for integer constants will not match base-10 numbers longer than two digits and octal numbers longer than three digits (2 if you don't count the leading zero). Since this is a homework, I leave it up to you to figure out what's wrong with it.

Hint: Google for "regular expression repetition quantifiers".

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

*Octal numbers:*

A string that start with a [0] , then can be followed by any digit 1, 2, .. 7 [1-7](assuming no leading zeroes) but can also contain zeroes after the first actual digit, so [0-7]* (* is for repetition, zero or more times).

So we get the following RegEx for this part: 0 [1-7][0-7]*

*Decimal numbers:*

Decimal numbers must not have a leading zero, hence start with all digits from 1 to 9 [1-9], but zeroes are allowed in all other positions as well hence we need to concatenate [0-9]*

So we get the following RegEx for this part: [1-9][0-9]*

Since we have two options (octal and decimal numbers) and either one is possible we can use the Alternation property '|' :

L = 0[1-7][0-7]* **|** [1-9][0-9]*

**Question 2:**

Quickly looking at Fermat's Last Theorem:

> In number theory, Fermat's Last Theorem (sometimes called Fermat's conjecture, especially in older texts) states that no three positive integers a, b, and c can satisfy the equation an + bn = cn for any integer value of n greater than two.
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

Hence the following sets where n<=2 satisfy the equation: {0,1,2}base10 = {0,1,10}base2

If any of those elements satisfy the equation, we use the Alternation |  (or)

So the regular expression can be: L = 0 | 1 | 10 but can also be L = 00 | 01 | 10 or even be L = 0 | 1 | 10 | 00 | 01

Or can be generalized into:

1. {0}  we can have infinite number of zeroes: 0*
2. {1}  we can have infinite number of zeroes followed by a 1: 0*1
3. {10} we can have infinite number of zeroes followed by 10: 0*10

So L = 0* **|** 0*1 **|** 0*10

Comment: Please explain your answer!

Comment: added some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

max answered the first question.

the second appears to be the unsolvable diophantine equation of fermat's last theorem. if h,i,j are non-zero integers, x can only be 1 or 2, so you're looking for

```
^0*10?$
```

does that help?

Comment: but jspcal is my answer to second one ((0|1){32}|1|(10)) correct?

Comment: it you remove the first term `(0|1){32}|` should work.... (prepend 0* if you want to match strings like "000001", and you would need to anchor the pattern (^$)

Answer (score 0):

There are several tool available to test regular expressions, such as [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/).

If you search for "regular expression test" you will find numerous links to online testers.